Are these 2 columns load-bearing?
everyone!
We have recently moved into this house where the previous homeowners did quite a bit of changes by removing lots of walls and making it "open concept." In the living area, there is a column there, as well as the dining area. However, just to note, in the dining area, they took up the lanai and made it into interior space. So when you see the blueprint, the living area column is in red, and the dining area living column is in blue. So, these are the two columns I'm trying to figure out if they're structural. Thank you all in advance!
Blueprint: https://i.imgur.com/dTj0JCN.jpg
Blueprint with highlighted columns: https://i.imgur.com/lmXJVFL.jpg
Columns:
https://i.imgur.com/1WGcr0R.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/zpUCWxy.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/oqDP5qx.jpg

They look big enough.  The ceiling looks like it might hide a beam.  What is under the floor where the columns are?  Load bearing is from the bottom up, so if there is a support beam/wall under the floor/columns, then the chance of them being supports/load bearing go way up, close to a 100%.

Columns are rarely installed just for decoration. Some "fake" columns could possibly serve as a chase to keep wiring and piping hidden, but otherwise it is reasonable to assume all columns are load-bearing.

They actually weren’t initially columns! There were walls there, but the previous homeowners remove alllll the walls and left these columns. So of course, naturally, you assume they left it because they’re structural. But to make sure, I figured to ask lol
